# Slow performance of XmlTextWriter under IIS 7.5

Tags: c#

We are in need of building a large **XML** file that contains Google’s feed.
If we execute the code in a Console application, or in an ASP.NET site running under IIS Express on a local machine, it runs very fast.

If we execute it in an  ASP.net  environment under IIS 7.5 (either as a webforms or MVC site) it performs dramatically slower.

We use an `xmltextwriter` object and we read data by means of an `SqlDataReader`,
Every time a row is read we create different nodes and we write them to disc.

```
xmlFeedWriterToFile = new XmlTextWriter(tempXmlfileName, Encoding.UTF8);
while (feedReader.Read())
{
    xmlFeedWriterToFile.WriteStartElement("item");
    // ID
    xmlFeedWriterToFile.WriteStartElement("id", "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0");
    if (this.ReturnSKULevelResults)
        // SKU-specific ID
        xmlFeedWriterToFile.WriteString(string.Format("{0}", feedReader.GetString(4)));
    else
    {
        xmlFeedWriterToFile.WriteString(string.Format("{0}_{1}", feedReader.GetString(1), feedReader.GetString(2)));
        xmlFeedWriterToFile.WriteEndElement();
    }
    // other code that writes XML nodes in the XmlTextWriter object
```

It seems that the ASP.Net application pool slows things down because the same routine is performed very fast in a console application.

We have also tried to deploy the web application on different WebServers but the result is the same:

Any idea to solve the issue would be appreciated.
Regards

Comment: The result of your profiling has identified that it's code within the `XmlTextWriter`, yes?

Comment: The comparison to console: is that based on the same two nodes? (the database server, and the node running this code); also - the file that is being written to: is that local? What sort of quantity of data (rows) are we talking about?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have written only two nodes, but there are around 20 nodes in the loop. The number of rows in the SqlDAtareader loop is around 160000 and the final file size of the xml file is 200 Mb. The file is local either cases. The comparison in terms of performances is the following: 15 minutes in a console application, and more than 5 hours in the web application. Different web servers on different machines are being used but the result is always the same.